# MinGW / GNU Make - "multiple target patterns"

Tags: makefile, mingw

I'm using MinGW 3.18 under Windows XP SP2, GNU make 3.82.

I'm trying to incorporate a value returned by a script in a path and receive an error.

This works:

```
PROD_DIR=$(ROOT_DIR)/PROD
version=1.1.1

PROD_SOURCE_files = \
    file1 \
    file2

PROD_TARGET_files = $(patsubst %,$(PROD_DIR)/$(version)/%,$(PROD_SOURCE_files))
```

This doesn't:

```
PROD_DIR=$(ROOT_DIR)/PROD
version=`get_version.sh`

PROD_SOURCE_files = \
    file1 \
    file2

PROD_TARGET_files = $(patsubst %,$(PROD_DIR)/$(version)/%,$(PROD_SOURCE_files))

Makefile:1359: *** multiple target patterns.  Stop.
```

(line 1359 is the definition of PROD_TARGET_files)

I've double-checked $(version), it has the same value in both cases, with apparently no leading/trailing blanks or newlines:

```
@echo [$(version)]
[1.1.1]
```

Comment: You have a Makefile that's (at least) 1359 lines long?  That makes me want to cry!

Comment: Are you sure it's set to the same value? For example, if it can't find the command it'd be set to `/bin/sh: get_version.sh: command not found` which contains colons and would cause that exact problem.

Answer (score 3):

Backticks (`) are a Bash thing, not a Make thing.

If you want to call out to an external shell, you should use the [`shell`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Shell-Function) function:

```
version=$(shell get_version.sh)
```

Comment: Backticks seem to work in gnu make, so even if $(shell) probably is better for compatibility, it shouldn't be the cause of the problem.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: It depends what you mean by "work"; Make certainly doesn't evaluate them.